# ftp issue ( from server to webhosting)

Tags: ftp

I have a web hosted on a sever where i have created an ftp user. now i m trying to access that ftp from a vps but when i give password it says me authentication faild.

```
[root@vps ~]# ftp ftp.asifrazaprep.com
Connected to ftp.asifrazaprep.com (174.142.92.112).
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 6 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 06:21. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (ftp.asifrazaprep.com:root): testuser
331 User testuser OK. Password required
Password:**********
530 Login authentication failed
Login failed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

this is what i m getting in log file grep fpt /var/log/messages

```
Mar 27 17:06:14 vps xinetd[1512]: START: ftp pid=28250 from=208.111.39.5
Mar 27 17:06:14 vps proftpd[28250]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - FTP session opened. 
Mar 27 17:06:14 vps proftpd[28250]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - client sent too-long command, ignoring 
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps proftpd[28250]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - FTP session closed. 
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps xinetd[1512]: EXIT: ftp status=0 pid=28250 duration=2(sec)
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps xinetd[1512]: START: ftp pid=28251 from=208.111.39.5
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps proftpd[28251]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - FTP session opened. 
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps proftpd[28251]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - FTP session closed. 
Mar 27 17:06:16 vps xinetd[1512]: EXIT: ftp status=0 pid=28251 duration=0(sec)
```

Comment: Did you look at the logs for pureftpd, as well as the auth.log (or whatever the equivalent is for the distro you're using)?

Comment: Can you update your question with the log entries?  Putting it in comments leaves the formatting almost unreadable.

Comment: If you installed this from a package, it was probably compile withparanoidmsg - which means that for whatever reason your login was rejected, the error will stay the same.  Those logfile entries look like they are generated by BIND or somesuch.  Which logfile are you looking at?

Comment: That's not the relevant log, as those are DNS log entries. What distro are you using?  Do a `cat /etc/issue.net` if you're not sure.  The log files you're interested in are the ones associated with login failures and with the pure-ftpd service in particular.

Comment: this is what i get by running issue command:..... CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m .... i jst got from google that ftp logs are in messages file thats why i checked there.

Comment: Look in /var/log/secure for general CentOS authentication messages.  The pure-ftpd package for CentOS defaults to using /var/log/pureftpd.log as the log file.  There might be entries in /var/log/messages, but you can't just post the most recent ones, since stuff is getting logged all the time.  Do a "grep ftp /var/log/messages" to check for anything that might related to ftp.

Answer (score 0):

> Mar 27 17:06:14 vps proftpd[28250]: vps.server.com (208.111.39.5[208.111.39.5]) - client sent too-long command, ignoring

Perhaps the password was too long ?

You really should know where your FTP server writes its login and authentication logs; this is crucial information.